# Django: I am unable to login as "user" from the user login page (after manually creating user in the admin page)

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

I am new to Django and created a project where a separate login page is created for the user. The user credentials are already created in the admin page under `Authentication and Authorization >> Users`. When I use the same login credentials in the user login page and click `"Log In"` button, it redirects to the login page again and shows invalid credentials even for correct credentials. I checked the credentials by inspecting the page and checking in the network tab. It returned 200 status code for invalid and valid credentials. Please tell me if I am missing something as I am not able to sort this out after so much research. I have connected sqlite3 database to my project by separately downloading it and it opens up when I give `python manage.py dbshell`. Is there anything wrong with my database? Why am I not able to login as a registered user? Project name - Project1 and App name- Authenticator

My project's urls.py file:

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('Authenticator.urls')),
    ]
```

My app's urls.py file:

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include
    from . import views
       
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', views.home, name="home"),
        path('', views.signin, name="signin"),
    ]
```

My views.py file:

```
    from django.shortcuts import  render, redirect
    from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate 
    from django.contrib import messages
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

    def home(request):
        pass
        
    def signin(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, template_name = "Authenticator/index.html")
        else:
            messages.error(request,"Wrong Credentials")
            return redirect('')
       else:
            form = AuthenticationForm()
            messages.error(request,"Invalid username or password")
            return render(request, "Authenticator/signin.html", {'form' : form})
```

my signin.html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load static %}
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Welcome User</title>
    <link href="{% static '/css/basic.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  >
    <!--link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous"-->
    </head>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <body>
      <div class = "login-form">
      <div class="form">
        
    <form class="login-form">
    <form action="signin/" method="post">
      
    {% if form.errors %}
      <p>username or password not correct</p>
    {% endif %}
      
      <!--label for="username">Username</label-->
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="" placeholder="Enter your username" Required />
      <br>

      <!--label for="password">Password</label-->
      <input  type="password" id="password" name="password" class="" placeholder="Enter a password" Required />
      <br>
      <button type="submit" style="background-color:#848387">Log In</button>&nbsp;
      <button type="submit" style="background-color:#848387"><a href="reset.html">Reset Password</a></button>&nbsp;
      <button type="submit" style="background-color:#848387"><a href="admin">Admin</a></button>&nbsp;
         
     </form>
     </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script src="" async defer></script>
    </html>
```

My models.py file

```
    from django.db import models

    class tbl_Authentication(models.Model):
        username = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
        password = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.username

    empAuth_objects = models.Manager()
```

My settings.py file:

```
    from pathlib import Path
    import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/



# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Authenticator',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Project1.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [r'C:\Python and Django\DjangoProject1\templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Project1.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'os.path.join(BASE_DIR, db.sqlite3)',
       
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Comment: Add your `Authenticator` inside `INSTALLED_APPS` after 'django.contrib.staticfiles' and try again

Comment: @user8193706: I did that but still the issue remains.